# How do I Iterate through Pages, find the text of a header and validate text using Selenium?

Tags: java, selenium

I am working on a script using Selenium with Java. I want to iterate through the beginning of a page that has a next button that will take you to next page.

Find the header text and decided if I want to click on complete or trash the header title using a trash button. If I match the `headers.getText` with my values store in a string of arrays, then I click on complete else click on the trash.

There is a next button on the side of the page to go through all pages with different text headers. I am having trouble with the string of array matching the `headers.getText` and actually going through all/next pages.

Here is my script:

`seriesHeader` is following pagefactory by xpath:

```
  String offers[] = { "Example1", "Example2", "Example3", "Example4",
        "Example15", "Example6", "Example7", "Example8" };
String sp=seriesHeader.getText();
System.out.println("SP1: " + sp);

   for (String offer : offers) {
    sp = seriesHeader.getText();
    System.out.println("Offer: " + offer);
    if (sp.equals(offer)) {
        Thread.sleep(3000);
        completeSeriesProfile.click();
        System.out.println("SP2: " + sp);
        System.out.println("Offer2: " + offer);}
    else if (!sp.equals(offer)) {
        Thread.sleep(3000);
        trashButton.click();
        confirmTrashButton.click();
        System.out.println("SP3: " + sp);
        System.out.println("Offer3: " + offer);} 
    else {nextButton.click();}}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please find the code sample, this will click the heading based on your xpath,

```
String previousURL = driver.getCurrentUrl();
for(int i=0; i<offers.lenth ; i++)
{

driver.findElement(By.xpath(offers[i])).click();
//Add wait if required
driver.get("previousURL")
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your time in answering but i don't think that would work. Let me share a link to what i am trying to work on.

Comment: https://automobiles.honda.com/?experience=shop&ef_id=1:1:1&CID=SEARCH_HRM_GOOGLE_EVERGREEN_HON_SHOPPERS&gclsrc=aw.ds&?gclid=EAIaIQobChMItNmF2cWD5QIVg9dkCh3plQqQEAAYASAAEgJaDfD_BwE&gclsrc=aw.ds

Comment: on that page. you will see right under Our Vehicle with cars from 1/13. I want to match my string of arrays with the text of the vehciles(header of the text) and either complete or trash. while also clicking the arrow next. I hope that makes sense.